# (Counting, permutations) Permutation with duplicates? How many distinct positive integers n that can be from x digits such that n> some value?

Tags: permutations, combinations

> Q: How many distinct positive integers n can be formed using only seven digits 2,3,4,4,5,6,7, such that n > 4,200,000?

> (Correct) answer is $ \frac{5\cdot6!}{2!} = 5\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3 = 1800 $

- Since n> 4,200,000; leading digit only has 5 choices (4,4,5,6,7)
- Since 2 is the lowest digit among the set, all remaining digits will be higher than X,200,000. So remaining choices for single permutation will be $6\cdot5\cdot...\cdot1= 6!$
- but since the question's asking for distinct integers, we need to account for the duplicate (4,4) so $\frac{1}{2!}$ (number of combinations you can make using those duplicate digits)

so overall $\frac{5*6!}{2!} = 1800$,
so each integer would look like $\frac{{5\choose1},{6\choose 1}{5\choose1}{4\choose1},{3\choose1}{2\choose1}{1\choose1}}{2!}$

**Here's my question.**
Why doesn't permutation formula account of the repeated digits? Why does
$5*P\binom{6}{6}=3,600$ still include the repeated 4s in it? I thought nPr already handled repetition?

Comment: Label the two digits of $4$ as $4_a$ and $4_b$.  $5 \times 6!$ allows $4_a$ and $4_b$ to occur in any order.  Compare the original problem, with the problem where the digits are $2,3,4,5,6,7,8$.  In the altered problem, $5 \times 6!$ would be correct.  Therefore, $5 \times 6!$ can **not** be correct in the original problem.

Comment: $^nP_r$ is *defined* as the permutations of $n$ **different** objects taken $r$ at a time.